# Exclude number from SecureRandom random number generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say we have a random number generator using this:

```
SecureRandom.random_number(10)
```

Which gives you a random number from 0 to 10.

Would it be possible to exclude the number from it? Let's say it would be 8.

I was thinking about something about this:

```
[SecureRandom.random_number(10)].grep_v(8)
```

But might be there is a more correct and optimized way?

Ruby 2.7.2

Rails 6.1.2

Comment: If `random_number` returns `8`, your approach would generate `[]`

Comment: If you know how many uniq numbers you want,: `sample ` takes an argument: `(1..10).to_a.sample(3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of generating a number up to 10, you could generate a number up to 9 and if the result is 8 or above, add 1:

```
number = SecureRandom.random_number(9)
number += 1 if number >= 8
```

Or you could generate a list of valid numbers and pick one of them randomly, e.g. via [`sample`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#sample-method):

```
VALID_NUMBERS = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]

number = VALID_NUMBERS.sample(random: SecureRandom)
```